# Content management systems and S3

Tags: open-source, permissions, content-management-system, file-sharing, amazon-s3

I wish to build a file sharing site and store the files in S3. I also wish to have different users upload their different files and be able to see them, have access to them (open, share etc.) and manage them (delete, edit etc.). I wish to set ownership for each file uploaded and access permissions for the users.

So I am thinking of using an open source CMS.

Is this a good approach? Is a CMS the right things to use here? Which is the best one to use with S3?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea is flying in the air. I suggest that you search [Amazon Web Services solution catalog](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=60) to see if somebody has created CMS bases on AWS already.